VBA Excel Paste into first empty cell
I need to copy data that is across multiple columns a-k from sheet "1.4 non standard changes" and paste the values as hard values to next empty cell that is in column d of sheet "recharges template" but the paste needs to start in column c of sheet "recharges template". This is because column d has data that needs to be overwritten with the new values.
The errror I get for my code below is "Run time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method".
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
Sub NonStandardChangesMacro()

Sheets("1.4 Non Standard Changes").Select
Range("A17").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("A17:K100000").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Recharges Template").Select
Sheets("Recharges Template").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1). _
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub


First of all, please, never ever post question using uppercases because that equals screaming. Second, Specify which lines throws the error. Third, not tested but I think you need Sheets("Recharges Template").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False (notice I deleted Selection)

Thank you. I've checked without the Selection as you suggested above and it doesn't work. The lines that throw the error are:
Sheets("Recharges Template").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1). _
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - out of curiosity (can take this one offline if req) - but you advise not to post with uppercase - even if specifying VBA/related code e.g. defining variables etc. ? e.g. "let X = ..."..  I can understand if you are referring to text in question itself (unless for the odd word like 'SHEET1'.  Perhaps I should see original question for context - notwithstanding... ?

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Just to mention the error I get if I delete Selection as per your comment above is a 'Syntax error'

I was referring to text itself in question. Your original post was I NEED TO COPY DATA... and it should be I need to copy data....

@Elena - I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve - first of all, you want to copy "all" values in columns a-k ("multiple" gives the impression that there are select multiple columns within this range).  Next - you say "the paste needs to start in col C"  - but then you go ahead and paste into column D (from the next blank after the last non-blank it seems)..  Does it need to start in col C or col D? so in other words, you want to copy all from A-K in sheet 1, and paste into D-N of sheet 2, s.t . you effectively append to whatever is in col D (sheet 2) ?

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns apologies, i tried to explain as much as I could but struggled, sorry for confusing you. I mentioned that I wanted the paste into col C onwards because column D may have data from another macro that I use in my file and I'm happy for the data in col D to be overwritten by the macro above, starting from the first empty row in col C. I may still not make sense, sorry. However, to keep it simpler I've now changed my Excel file so there is no data in col D if there is no data in col C. Your advice to delete Selection above has now worked and was useful. Thanks

It should work OK if you select the destination cell that is at the top left of where you want the (rather large) copy to land. ie. Sheets("Recharges Template").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False  done as two separate statements. If that still doesn't work try  hard wired    Range("G7").Select to test the paste special action. If all else fails record a macro whilst trying to do it manually and compare carefully with your code.
